# How to use Jquery and Google Maps API to convert street address from array to lat/long

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to output the lat and long of each address in my array.

Please refer to fiddle: http://jsbin.com/simumo/5/edit?html,js,console,output

JavaScript:

```
var address = [ "Collins+Street,+MELBOURNE,+VIC,+AUSTRALIA,+3000", "Sussex+Street,+SYDNEY,+NSW,+AUSTRALIA,+2000", "George+Street,+BRISBANE,+QLD,+AUSTRALIA,+4000"];

jQuery.each(address, function(index, item) {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
    } 
});
```

I think my iteration is a bit messed up. My end goal is to display these as a list but I'll settle for the console for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few Syntax errors, here is what your final code should look like:

```
var address = [ "Collins+Street,+MELBOURNE,+VIC,+AUSTRALIA,+3000", "Sussex+Street,+SYDNEY,+NSW,+AUSTRALIA,+2000", "George+Street,+BRISBANE,+QLD,+AUSTRALIA,+4000"];

jQuery.each(address, function(index, item) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': item}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      console.log(latitude, longitude);
    } 
   });
  });
```

Also note how I changed

```
 {'address': address}
```

to

```
{'address':item}
```

Because we are now referencing the items and indexes of the array itself!

Here is a working demo: http://jsbin.com/vujuwoco/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Excellent answer and explanation. Thanks hellojebus.